# MySQL query not working with PHP from $_GET

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot seem to pass $_GET into my MYSQL query.  Lets say I have 2 tables in my DB, example1 and example2.  I would like to query the table selected from the previous page.  If I simply put the table into the query it runs fine.  Here is what I have so far...

```
<html>

<form id="area" name="area" method="GET" action="test.php">
        Select: 
        <select id="area" name="area">
            <option value="example1">Example1</option>
            <option value="example2">Example2</option>  
        </select><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</html>
```

test.php

```
include "connect.php";
$area = $_GET['area'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM '$area' ";
$query = mysqli_query($sql);

if (isset($_POST['searchquery'])) {

$search_term = $_POST['searchquery'];
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

}

?>

<strong>Search</strong>
<p>
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    Search: <input type="text" name="searchquery" />
    <input type="submit" name="searchname" value="Search">
</form>

<table class="sortable.js" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspace="0">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>1</strong></td>
        <td><strong>2</strong></td>
        <td><strong>3</strong></td>
        <td><strong>4</strong></td>
    </tr>

<?php   
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['1']; ?>
        <td><?php echo $row['2']; ?>
        <td><?php echo $row['3']; ?>
        <td><?php echo $row['4']; ?>

<?php } ?>
</table>
```

If I echo $area it will show properly.

Comment: Your form and `<select>` have the same `id` and `name`. Change the form values and try it again.

Comment: You're using both $_POST and $_GET

Comment: The first parameter of `mysqli_query()` when used in procedural style needs to be the connection link from when you connected to MySQL. Secondly, **that SQL is stupidly vulnerable to SQL injection!!!!** Also your form and your select have the same name, change them.

Comment: Have you tried to run `SELECT * FROM '$area'` query with a value substituted? Why do you think it must work?

Comment: @andrewsi nothing wrong with that - it's totally feasible to post a form to `script.php?foo=bar`

Comment: @scrowler - you're quite right. But in the posted code, he isn't. The first form uses GET while the second uses POST, both with the same action; and the code uses a mixture of POST and GET variables.

Comment: @andrewsi from what I can see, they are two separate forms with incomplete processing code

Comment: @zerkms Yes, If I try it with the table name instead of the variable it works fine

Comment: @cableguy: it's not possible. You probably run a query without single quotes around a table name then. They are significant, you cannot put single quotes character wherever you like or randomly.

Comment: Single quotes are used for **values**, not table or column names.

Answer (score 1):

Your table name is quoted. Either remove the quote or use escape character like tick

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$area` ";
```

Comment: While you're correct, that's only one of the many reasons this script isn't working.

Comment: I removed the quotes and I am getting the same thing

Comment: You said if you hardcode the table like `$sql = "SELECT * FROM example1";`, it works fines. But when it's `$area = 'example1'; $sql = "SELECT * FROM $area";`, it fails?

Comment: If I set $area = 'example1'; $sql = "SELECT * FROM $area"; It works.  It seems that I am not able to set $area = '$_GET['area']';

Comment: @Fabricator It does work which is why I am confused.  $area = $_GET['area'];
echo $area;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $area";  I see the variable with that code, but for some reason doesn't work in the query

Answer (score 1):

Unlike ***mysql_(), mysqli_*** functions require the connection to be specified explicitly. On the statement `$query = mysqli_query($sql);` you used msqli_ but you didn't provide the connection (mysqli link resource variable ) you should pass in the connection as the firs parameter of the call like this `$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);` . And also, don't forget to select a database. you can select a database like this. `mysqli_select_db($connection,"database_name");` Remember to replace `$connection` with your connection variable name.

Answer (score -1):

I found that the following was the solution to my problem.

I changed:

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="test.php?area=<?php echo $area?>" method="POST">
```

Thanks for everyone help!